# Sending audio to client using .pipe(res) doesn't allow you to seek?

Tags: node.js, express

If I pipe'd an mp3 file through an express.js server like this:

```
createReadStream('media/mp3file.mp3').pipe(res)
```

It sends the audio data but I cannot seek. It just quickly pauses the audio, moves the seek bar back to the current time and then resumes the audio.

Here is a GIF:

[image: 1]

How do I make it so I can seek forwards and backwards?

Comment: Try using [`res.sendFile()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile), which supports ranges.

Comment: Using that makes it download the file and not play it in the browser... edit: or not! post that as an answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: but what if I wanted to render a webpage and put that audio in?

Comment: @HeyHoo Then you still need to send the file to the client. With additional headers that support the client to seek or not.

Comment: Hm, how would I do that and also make the audio player play it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streaming file data from the server doesn't allow for seeking because it's a one-off operation from the context of the server.

To enable seeking the server needs to allow [HTTP range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests), where a client tells it that it wants to receive a part of a download (starting at byte X, ending at byte Y, the "range" part).

Express support such requests when you use [`res.sendFile()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile) to send the file data.

If you want to render a web page with an audio player, you need to add (at least) two handlers: one for the HTML file, and one for the audio file. If you're just using regular plain HTML files, you can use the [`express.static()` middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static), which you point to a directory that contains your HTML files.